# select a database and in that select tables. using c# . use web config

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net windows form application. 
I have many databases created using sql server Management studio 2005. Each database has several tables. i have a button, when clicked should allow me to select a database among several databases and in that database i want to select a single table. Later i need to display the contents of the selected table into a datagrid view.I came to know that it can be done using Webconfig. How can i acheive this?

It goes like this
a) select a database
b) In that database select a table
c) display the contents into a datagridview.

Comment: What has web.config got to do with this at all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some things mixed up a bit. A web.config file is only used for web applications created with ASP.Net.

For windows application you can use the App.config file, which is like the web.config for web applications. As part of the app.config is the "connectionStrings" section which contains one or multiple connection string for database connections. Take a look at this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28VS.80%29.aspx

In code you then can retrieve the connections string via the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "programming". Good enough an answer? I mean, you basically ask a LOT ;)

Ok, here some details:

- You need to log into the server, obviously.
- Then find out what databases exist. MASTER database is your friend - look at the sys schema there, you will find out the tables there contain all information.
- Then you need to find out what tales exist. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA is your friend. It exists in every database. It has nice views that allow you to ask for tables, columns etc.

From there on it is some low level beginner training - given a database and table name, how do you get the data? ;)